# How to use zurb foundation with Ruby on Rails Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zurb-foundation

Can't figure out exactly where and how to use the out-of-the-box RTL and be able to switch it according to different locals using the Ruby Gem.

http://www.zurb.com/playground/foundation-rtl

UPDATE:
On the Zurb website it says:
"Sassy RTL
If you're using the Foundation Gem version, RTL support comes built-in, and switching text directions is easier than ever. You only need to change a single variable in the Settings SCSS file."

```
$textDirection: rtl !default;
```

what is this file and where do I add this code?

Comment: Elan -- this isn't a specific question.  What have you tried?  What's not working?  If you're looking for examples, probably the zurb site would be more fruitful.  I think people will be happy to help if you can show some more detail about what you want, and what's not working.

Comment: I tried following their example... adding it in the app.scss file... they wrote on their website "If you're using the Foundation Gem version, RTL support comes built-in, and switching text directions is easier than ever. You only need to change a single variable in the Settings SCSS file." - I can't figure out what they mean and there is no answers out there.